# Capture Screenshot as a scheduled task on a server using c#

Tags: c#, screenshot, rdp

I had written the following c# code and would like to run it as a scheduled task on a server. However I get exception due to this part of the code. I am assuming that the error has got to do with fact that there is no screen. Has anybody found a way to capture the screen as a scheduled task and not connected to the remote system?

```
Bitmap bt;
        // a browser is running  for which screen shot needs to be taken.
            bt = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);//use 24bbp for capture image as AForge supports only 24bpp.
        Graphics screenShot = Graphics.FromImage(bt);

        screenShot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

        bt.Save(@"C:\folder\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

since i am running it on a server it has no physical monitor attached to it i have to remote to the server. When i run it manually there is no error. However when i schedule it and log off from the machine it gives me the below message

```
Application: ConsoleAppCaptureScreenshot.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Stack:
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CopyFromScreen(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32,      System.Drawing.Size, System.Drawing.CopyPixelOperation)
   at ConsoleAppCaptureScreenshot.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

Comment: What is the exception, and also you mention rdp etc? Don't read anything about that? You mean no physical screen is attached? The Screen object isn't referring to an actual screen :)